# Media codec api

Tags: android, media

Can you tell me if android api media codec can encode and compress video (like ffmpeg lib)?
Can you please provide source?

I can 't find anything showing how to compress a video using media codec. Any documentation or sample is welcome.

Media codec: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

Answer (score 3):

```
               FFmpeg       MediaCodec
    demuxing      +              +
    decoding      +              +
    resizing      +              -
    encoding      +              +
    muxing        +              -
```

Can't say anything about audio.

Answer (score 0):

Some information and sample code is available [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).  In particular, the code demonstrates creation of a .mp4 from camera input and from OpenGL ES rendering, using `MediaCodec` and `MediaMuxer`.

Much of the code requires Android 4.3 (API 18).